# JSHint Object is not defined error when using Jasmine

Tags: javascript

I am using Jasmine to TDD some JavaScript code.

I have an object Game, and within I want to call another object Frame that I have coded in a different file.

the line that invokes that Frame object is:

```
frame = new Frame(number);
```

JSHint complains with the error: `'Frame' is not defined`, however the code works.

How could I get rid of this error?

Comment: `/* global Frame */` at the top of the file?

Comment: thank you Andy, unfortunately it does not seem to work, if in comments it remains the same, if I remove the /* */ it creates more errors.

Comment: Sorry, just looked [at the docs](http://jshint.com/docs/). Try `/* globals Frame */`.

Comment: that certainly works! Thank you so much Andy